# Puppeteer Web Crawling Navigation lock on click

Tags: javascript, web-crawler, puppeteer

I am writing a puppeteer web crawler, what it does is:

1. Given a list of url in list format
2. Open each url in puppeteer
3. Find all buttons present in the web page
4. Click on each of the button, while listening to the network trace to extract the XHR Post request

## Problem

1. It works fine for non navigation buttons, but for most login/submit button, it will perform a redirect/navigation to a different page, which lead to the following error when trying to perform click for any buttons found in the current page or any action on the original page, and since I don't know which button will trigger the navigation, I need a good way to block navigation from all buttons

   - Error: Execution context was destroyed, most likely because of a navigation.
2. I originally thought preventDefault will do the job, but it doesn't really work

I wanted to know if there is a good way to disable page navigation?

Below is my code on extracting and clicking of the buttons

```js
    listenAndLogResources() {
        this.page.on('console', msg => console.log(msg.text()));
        this.page.on('request', (request) => {
            let urlBucket = this.resources.get(request.resourceType()) === undefined ?
                new Set() :
                this.resources.get(request.resourceType());

            if (request.resourceType() === "xhr") {
                urlBucket.add({
                    "url": request.url(),
                    "postData": request.postData(),
                    "header": request.headers()
                });
            } else {
                urlBucket.add(request.url());
            }

            this.resources.set(request.resourceType(), urlBucket);
            request.continue();
        });
    }

    async findAndClickOnAllButtons() {
        return await Promise.all([
            this.page.evaluate(() => {
                const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('button');
                for (let button of buttons) {
                    button.click((e) => e.preventDefault());
                    console.log("button clicked");
                }
            }),

            this.page.evaluate(() => {
                const inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input');
                for (let input of inputs) {
                    if (input.type === "button" || input.type === "submit") {
                        input.click((e) => e.preventDefault());
                        console.log("input clicked");
                    }
                }
            })]);
    }
```

Been reading some forums, and people mentioned blocking navigation request

```js
    //Prevent navigation
    if (request.isNavigationRequest() && request.frame() === this.page.mainFrame() && request.url() !== this.url) {
        request.abort();
    }
```

Though it is not working out for me

A simple test against [www.facebook.com](http://www.facebook.com)

```js
document.querySelectorAll('button')[0].click((e) => e.preventDefault())
```

Doesn't prevent page navigation :(

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?  I need the exact same thing.